# Why do we call microwave ovens by the adjective, not the noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-order

Most people know that **microwave** is short for **microwave oven**.

In English, we typically refer to things by the noun, not the adjective - for instance, we can call a green umbrella an umbrella, but not just 'a green'. Likewise, adjectives come before the noun in English.

I am pretty sure that *microwave* is the adjective and *oven* is the noun, since it is an oven that uses microwave radiation to cook food. Is there a particular reason we call 'microwave ovens' *microwaves*, or was that just to avoid confusion with a conventional oven?

I ask because I do a lot of work with radiation and wireless technologies, and I'm kind of annoyed that we use the same word for these "microwave ovens" as well as the actual type of electromagnetic wave that it uses.

Comment: To distinguish it from ovens in general?

Comment: *Microwaves* are actual *things*, so I'd say the usage is a ***noun adjunct***, not an adjective in the usual sense. An example of an adjective that we use as a noun is right here on this page - the English language is usually just called ***English***. There are loads more - *I'll have a pint of **bitter** [ale]*, for example.

Comment: Its almost like  washer rather than washing machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an extension of what happens when a [retronym](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/retronym) is formed.

> That's a nice guitar.
>   Glad you like it; it's an acoustic.

The noun (guitar) is dropped when the context is clear.

> I love your car, is it an automatic or a manual?

(transmission)

Comment: Great example! Now that I look at it, it makes loads more sense